# What is the largest sigma-field on R ? And also what is borel sigma field?

Tags: probability, abstract-algebra, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, borel-sets

I take taking an introductory course on probability and stochastic processes and want to understand the sigma field on R.
What is the largest sigma-field on R ? And also what is the Borel sigma field?

Omega (Sample Space) = R
F' = {phi, omega, (a,inf), (a,b], (-inf,a), [a,inf), (a,b), [a,b], [a,b), {a} }
Is F' a borel sigma field?

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by largest? One that contains most sets? Well, you can take the power set of $\mathbb{R}$, it is a sigma field. (though a not so interesting one, it contains way too many sets, so it's difficult to define an interesting measure on it)

As for Borel sigma field, this is the smallest sigma field which contains all the open subsets of $\mathbb{R}$. A formal definition-the intersection of all sigma fields on $\mathbb{R}$ which contain all the open sets. (it is easy to check that any intersection of sigma fields is also a sigma field). Now this is really an important sigma field-it isn't too large but still contains all the "good sets".

Comment: What do you mean by all the open subsets? And is the largest sigma field on R an uncountably infinite set?

Comment: The power set of $\mathbb{R}$ has cardinality $2^{|\mathbb{R}|}=2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$. So it's not just uncountable, it is even larger than $\mathbb{R}$. As for open sets, this is the standard definition: a subset $O\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ is open if for every $x\in O$ there is some $\delta>0$ such that the interval $(x-\delta, x+\delta)$ is contained in $O$. ($\delta$ depends on the point $x$). For example, any open interval is open.

Comment: How to find the Borel field on R?

Comment: Well, start by taking all the open sets. Since you want to find a sigma field you need to add all of their complements (which are the closed sets), countable unions and intersections. So this sigma field must also contain countable intersections of open sets and countable unions of closed sets. This collection is still not a sigma field, you again have to take complements, countable unions and intersections of these sets. Then repeat it again and again. Finally, we need to use transfinite induction to prove the process will eventually stop. So yeah, it's not easy.

Comment: please see the new change in question.

Comment: I suppose you defined it for all $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$. No, the set you defined is contained in the Borel sigma field, but still not equal to it. As I said, you need to take countable unions and intersection of such sets, and keep doing that again and again. (formally by transfinite induction). So it's difficult to describe all Borel sets. But yes, the sets you defined are Borel sets, the most basic ones.